# There are at most four mutually visible lattice points—?

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-geometry, lattices, lattice-polytopes

Say that two lattice points $a$ and $b$ of $\mathbb{Z}^2$
are *visible* to one another if the line segment $ab$
contains no other lattice points.
While exploring lattice polygons all of whose vertices
are visible to one another, I noticed that it seems impossible
to have more than $4$ mutually visible lattice points.

---

[image]

---

> ***Q1***. Prove that there is no set of $\ge 5$ distinct points of
> $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that are mutually visible to one another,
> or construct examples.

I suspect this is elementary,
but I'm not seeing a proof or a refutation.

> ***Q2***. What is the higher-dimensional analog?
> What is the largest number $f(d)$ of mutually visible points of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ ?

Comment: Is it simply that if a = b (mod 2) then a is not visible to b, and there are only 4 options for coordinates in Z^2 mod 2?

Comment: @YoavKallus: This would then suggest the bound of $2^d$ for $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

Comment: Indeed $f(d)=2^d$ is then immediate with this argument (achieved by $\{0,1\}^d$ as well as its images by elements of $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbf{Z})$).

Comment: @YoavKallus: Very nice observation! If $a \equiv b \pmod 2$ then $a-b \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and $a-b$ has two even coordinates, and so the midpoint of $ab$ is a lattice point.

Comment: The problem for $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is Problem A1 on the 32nd Putnam exam (1971). See https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/putn71.html.

Answer (score 7):

(Inspired by [a meta thread on answers given in comments](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4841/answers-in-comments-are-increasingly-more-common), I am recapping the answer given in the comments ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376289/there-are-at-most-four-mutually-visible-lattice-points#comment954042_376289) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376289/there-are-at-most-four-mutually-visible-lattice-points#comment954043_376289) [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376289/there-are-at-most-four-mutually-visible-lattice-points#comment954044_376289)) as a CW answer.)

The largest number of mutually visible points in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ is $2^d$. This is achieved, for example, by the points $\lbrace 0, 1\rbrace^d$. Since there are $2^d$ orbits of $(2\mathbb{Z})^d$ in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and two points in the same orbit are not mutually visble (the midpoint of the segment connecting them is a lattice point), no more than $2^d$ points can be pairwise mutually visible.

Comment: Since this is [your own answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376289/there-are-at-most-four-mutually-visible-lattice-points#comment954042_376289), CW is surely not obligatory!