# Bound on mutually x-ray-visible lattice points?

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-geometry, lattices, lattice-polytopes

Say that two lattice points $a$ and $b$ of $\mathbb{Z}^d$
are *$x$-visible* to one another if the segment $ab$
contains at most $x$ lattice points (excluding $a$ and $b$).
So $x$-visiblity is "x-ray visibility," with the power to
see through $\le x$ blocking lattice points.
For normal lattice visibility, $0$-visibility, there
are at most $2^d$ mutually $0$-visible points, as established in
[an earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/376289/6094).

> ***Q***. For a given $x$ and $d$, what is the largest number
> of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ lattice points that are mutually $x$-visible?

Call this number $g(x,d)$. For example, although
$g(0,2)=4$, $g(1,2) \ge 9$ (*now corrected*):

---

[image]

---

Comment: In the picture, the two points in the top left and bottom left corner are not $1$-visible.

Comment: @JanKyncl: You are right---My error! Now corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The largest number is $g(x,d) = (x+2)^d$, by an analogous argument as for visibility: if the differences of all coordinates of two points $A,B$ are divisible by $x+2$, then there are at least $x$ lattice points in the interior of the segment $AB$.

The set $\{0,1,\dots, x+1\}^d$ gives the lower bound.